# Is there a way to fetch colors stored from the Back End and place them in SCSS file

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, less

At the moment i'am currently re-factoring my code . So that means more clearness and higher maintance . I have an idea in my head , but unfortunately i don't know how this can be realeased. 
In order to be more clean and effecient i want to create an isolated `_colors.scss` file that will contain all of my colors for the app . In other words i want it to look something like this 
 
`$colorPrimary: branding.colorPrimary,
$colorSecondary: branding.colorSecondary
...`

At the moment is pretty messy because the color styling is maintened at the component level , but i want to do this seperately . 
Ex:

```
<button style={
   color: branding.colorPrimary,
   background: branding.colorSecondary>
Hello
</button>
```

The colors are stored on the BE side so if i want to react them i have to do a call . I will be glad if someone can give me a hand with this mindf****. Thank you .

Comment: Why is it store on backend ? Can be edited by user from your back office ? is it global for all user on the application or it can be scoped ? Have you any constraint about Internet explorer ?

Comment: Why not serve the css files from the backend?

Comment: i think scss is converted to css when you build your app. its a preprocessor. so even if it was possible to change css **files** with js(i dont know how!) you couldnt change scss vars since they no longer exist

Comment: They are stored in the BE , because different user will use different color scheme . So in order to have them dynamically the BE sends me the right colors for the right user .

Comment: do you need internet explorer support ?

Comment: @Yanis-git not a priority but it will be a good idea to have the IE support also .

Comment: I just wonder is there a way to do something like this inside of my `scss` file : 
`let color = localStorage.getItem('colors')` ? Because i realized i can fetch them already from my local storage . But furher i know only JS can manage the storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to acheive this behavior you have two main way to do it. the first one describe are not compatible with Internet Explorer.

On last CSS version describe on [W3C](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/#using-variables) we are able to have variable directly on CSS.

Like this backend can do something like this :

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        :root {
          --primary-color: #cecece;
          --secondary-color: #fefefe;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

then on your scss (or css) you can do something like :

```
.mySelector {
   color: var(--primary-color, black);
}
```

which will be basically interpret as :

```
.mySelector {
    color: #cecece;
}
```

Or fallback in color `black` if `--primary-color` is not defined.

As you can imagine, is very easy for backend to prepare the configuration for frontend. And from your side (as front end) you can simply use what is already available on CSS API tools.

---

But if you are looking for something which are compatible with IE. You probably need more complex infrastructure.

> Goal is to spawn webpack sass compilation, on each User color change,
>   to build css output with relevant variable configuration.

for that you will need [SaSS ressource loader](https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader) which automatically inject sass file on all other file. Is like adding `@import "_colors"` automatically.

then backend server will have to :

1. Write _color.scss file somewhere (let say /user/123/_color.scss)
2. Ask for compilation like `webpack client 123`
3. read the output webpack folder for client 123 and detect if specific CSS exist
4. Inject on your head HTML.

---

For webpack configuration

on your webpack you will have something like :

```
   const argv = require("yargs").argv;
    entry: {
        [...]
    },
    output: {
      // Take the argument as clientId and craft dedicated output folder.
      path: helpers.root(`public/themes/front/${argv.client}`), 
      filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
      chunkFilename: "[name].[contenthash].js"
    }
```

Like this base on the client id you will store the outputed CSS on specific folder.

Finally the SaSS rules will looks like :

```
 {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'postcss-loader',
        'sass-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
          options: {
            resources: (argv.client) ? `/user/${ argv.client }/_color.scss` : `/user/default/_color.scss`,
          },
        },
      ],
    }
```